# How to check for parity in a condition?

Tags: flutter, dart

I get the number through the expression:

```js
numberPages: (_numPages / 15).round() + 1
```

It gives me the number of pages needed. But it's only correct when there is a remainder after (_numPages/15) and then I add + 1. How to write a condition that if (_numPages / 15) there is a remainder, then we add 1, and if not, then we just get the result

Comment: you described the ceil function (opposed to floor it rounds to the highest integer) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil there's no need for you to take into account that reminder strategy.. but if you really wanted to, you needed a combination of % (modulo operator) and ternary operator: (eg.: `numberPages: ((_numPages % 15) > 0) ? (_numPages / 15).round()+1 : (_numPages / 15)`). Anyway I'm quite sure you intended to use floor and not round. There's a chance you don't know that round actually rounds to the nearest integer

Comment: @DiegoDeVita Why don't you take your time to post this as an answer?

Comment: we have a very common XY problem here with some added misunderstanding of what was going on there. In this case is very hard to give an answer because you are not sure if the OP gets what's wrong with the expectation. It's like explaining a book to someone that can't even read. My first comment was some sort of bait waiting for a feedback that never arrived.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for parity manually by yourself. You can implement the logic by checking the `quotient` and `remainder`. If `remainder` is `0`, then `pageCount` is equals to `quotient` otherwise it is going to be `quotient + 1`;

```dart
int getNumberOfPagesFor({required int itemCount,  int itemsPerPage = 15}){
    
  final int quotient = itemCount ~/ itemsPerPage;
  final int remainder = itemCount % itemsPerPage;
  
  final int pageCount = remainder == 0 ? quotient: quotient + 1;
    
  return pageCount;
  
}
```